# JavaScript support in HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

When I get response this way

```
String url = "http://myurl.com/read.php";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
String result = response.toString();
```

I get in `result` long html code which contains the following info

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable
>   Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript
>   support

But real response should contains only one world. 
So what is wrong with my code? How to get a real response?

Comment: It sounds like the URL you're requesting data from isn't designed to be a machine interface.  Have you tried accessing it with wget or curl?  Do you get the same response?

Comment: @hugh I need to access it from java code

Comment: @thinker Java code does not run JS code and there might be some validation at server side, you might need some research around this website

Comment: @thinker Sure, but first you should verify what the behaviour of the page is. This looks like it isn't a problem with your code, it's that you're making the wrong request - trying it first with wget will help you diagnose the problem more easily.